# I need to automatically allow access to private key

Tags: credentials, cacls

I have search and could not find anything specifically relating to my issue.

My client made changes last week with regards to service accounts etc after a malware attack.

Now my software does not authenticate via A.D. accounts anymore.

I used a little A.D. login test app to test and get the following when I attempt to login:
[Credential Required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXGFo.png)

When I "allow" it logs in fine and again for rest of the session but upon restart same happens.

No, my software uses a Windows Service (c#) to authenticate users. This service logs in using a service account. The IIS application pools also use this same service account. All works fine except for the A.D. logins.

Microsoft has a FindPrivateKey sample with which you can apparently find the mentioned private key file and then to use the cacls.exe tool to give the services access to the private key file.

Is this sufficient? Does it have an effect if I do not login as the service account as it does not allow interactive login?